# How to scrape content from different html tags

Tags: python, selenium

Source website:

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<p>Example 2</p>
<h3>Exmaple 3</h3>
</div>
```

My Code:

```py
content=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="content"]/h1')
full_content=""
for des in content:
    full_content+='\n\n'+des.text
    suggest=[page_link,full_content]
    print(suggest)
```

I don't want to scrape everything from inside the '*content*' class, only text from certain tags like *h1* *h3*, but i want all that within `full_content`. Can i do it with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

The *`<h1>`* element is the immediate descendant of it's parent *`<div>`*

So to scrape the texts from certain tags you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *innerText* from *`<h1>`* tag:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']/h1").text)
  ```
- *innerText* from *`<h3>`* tag:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']//h3").text)
  ```